# send data with json format in angular 8 with formData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to send data from server by this format :

```
{
    "name":"kianoush",
    "userName":"kia9372",
    "email":"kiadr9372@gmail.com"
}
```

i try to do this work :

```
update(item:UserEditModel): Observable<any>{

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    for (const key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            if (item[key] instanceof File) {
                formData.append(key, item[key], item[key].name);
            } else {
                formData.append(key, item[key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return this.httpClient.post(this.appConfig.apiEndpoint+'User/UpdateUser',
     formData, {
         headers:this.headers,
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events'
    })
    .pipe(map(response => response || {} as HttpEvent<any>));
}
```

but it send to server by this format :

```
     ------WebKitFormBoundaryhWmbFWpD25WdeB9n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"

vbnvbnvb
------WebKitFormBoundaryhWmbFWpD25WdeB9n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"

vbnvbnvn
------WebKitFormBoundaryhWmbFWpD25WdeB9n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userName"

vbnvbnvb
------WebKitFormBoundaryhWmbFWpD25WdeB9n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="roleId"
```

but i want to send data from server by this format :

```
   {
    "name":"kianoush",
    "userName":"kia9372",
    "email":"kiadr9372@gmail.com"
  }
```

**now how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 0):

> because you have the formdata its format is deferent from JSON 
>   And if you don't have a file in the request just convert the formdata
>   to JSON
>
> Or in the backend use [FromForm] before the dto

Normally when I have some files that should go to the server
 I am using this kind of solution you can do it like this

**First:**

```
slectedFile: File;
//imgUrl for showing it in the html tag
imgUrl = '../assets/img/profilepic.png';
```

**Second:**

```
form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
   //........
   file: [null]
});
```

**Third:**

```
onFileSelect(file) {
    if (file.target.files[0]) {
      this.slectedFile = file.target.files[0] as File;
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.slectedFile);
      reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        this.imgUrl = event.target.result;
      };
   }
}
```

**And Last:**

> which I assume your main problem is here

```
  const data= new FormData();
  if (this.slectedFile) {
    data.append('file', this.slectedFile, this.slectedFile.name);
  }
```

and I should mention that personally use this package for input

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-file-input

and in the html side you just say :

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-12 ml-10 ngxmatfileinput">
    <ngx-mat-file-input
    (change)="onFileSelect($event)"
    formControlName="file"
    accept="image/*">
    </ngx-mat-file-input>
    <img [src]="imgUrl" class="float-left icon-fileupload" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you not send file use following code

```
  update(item:UserEditModel): Observable<any>{

        const _data ={
        "name":"item.name",
        "userName":"item.userName",
        "email":"item.email"
    }
        return this.httpClient.post(this.appConfig.apiEndpoint+'User/UpdateUser',
         _data)
        .pipe(map(response => response || {} as HttpEvent<any>));
    }
```